# Observe the list of names accessed during eval

Tags: python

Consider

```
eval('x + y')
```

I want to supply a function `get_name(name)` which when called returns the value to be used for the names and records in a global registry that this evaluation required names x and y (required in my application). I see no way to do this.

One way I am thinking of to solve is to try evaluating and catching the NameErrors, each time calling `get_name(name)` and supplying the result to the namespace argument of `eval`.

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

**Side question:**

Is there a better way to infer the name from the `NameError` exception than to write a *regular expression*.

Comment: That's an extremely non-deterministic approach. To really do this well, you need a Python parser that can parse the snippet and return structured information about it to you.

Comment: im not entirley sure what you are trying to do but you may want to look at the `ast` module, specifically try `ast.dump(ast.parse("x+y"))`